# share data between sibling directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Currently, I am facing one issue related to angularjs directive. I want to send outlet object from directive1 to directive2. Both directives having same controller scope. I tried with emitting event from directive1 to controller, broadcasting that event from controller to directive2 and listening to that event on directive2. but that is not working.

Directive1:

```
angular.module('moduleName')
.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directive1.html',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.selectOutlet = function(outlet) {
                scope.order.entityId = outlet.id;
                scope.navigation.currentTab = 'right';
            };
        }
    };
```

Here, in directive1, scope.selectOutlet() setting outletId to scope.order.entityId. I want to move/set that line to directive2 save function.

Directive2:

```
angular.module('moduleName')
.directive('directive2', function(config, $rootScope, $state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directive2.html',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.save = function() {
                // Save functionality  
                // scope.order.entityId = outlet.id; This is what i want to do
            };
        }
    };
});
```

});

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a factory or a service. Inject that factory into your directive. Now when you are trying set the data in function written into factory.  `app.factory('shared',function(){
var obj ={};

```
obj.setData = function(){
// call this function from directive 1.
 }
 return obj;
})`
```

So if you include this factory into your directives you will get the data in 2 directives.

I will try to make some jsfiddle or plunker. If it is not clear.

Comment: Can you create plunker? I created `angular.module('assetsApp').service('SharedService', function() {
    return {
        sharedObject: {
            confirmOrdering: false
        }
    };
});`

and injected this into controller and directive but not getting updated value in controller.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shardulpendse/02eykvwy/ 

just check the above jsFiddle. Though it is not perfect. But if we want to change the value once 1 value is change then we can do it using broadcast or using watch. it is 2nd part. It can be enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in first directive

```
angular.module('moduleName')
  .directive('directive1', function($rootScope) {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directive1.html',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.selectOutlet = function(outlet) {
             $rootScope.$broadcast('save:outlet',outlet);
            //scope.order.entityId = outlet.id;
            //scope.navigation.currentTab = 'right';
        };
    }
};
```

and in second

```
angular.module('moduleName')
 .directive('directive2', function(config, $rootScope, $state) {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directive2.html',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope) {
       $rootScope.$on('save:outlet',function(event,data){
         // do staff here 
       });
    }
   };
 });
```

Comment: You can modify my answer as you want. But broadcast should work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But outlet in directive2 is not exist. Outlet gets set in directive1 from function call. `$rootScope.$broadcast('save:outlet',outlet);` will not work.

Comment: @VishalRajole I fixed the answer please have a look.